# MySQL where not exist not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the result of a record which has a missing entry in the other table. I already tried using NOT IN and NOT EXIST but I cannot get the desired result. The output should be US Visa since my user has no US Visa on the table tbl_personnel_documents but I always get an empty row.

Note: I am trying to get the result by using only the vessel_id and lastJoinedVsl which in this case is id number 4.

Here's my code and sample data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46790e/1

Please help. 
Many Thanks

Comment: I don't even know why down voting my post? I am not trying to get a spoonfeed here. I just want some suggestion or correction in my code. I ain't no expert and still learning that's why I'm asking for some help here.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46790e/16)

The query should be :

```
SELECT tpi.name, td.documentName
FROM tbl_documents AS td
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd ON td.id=tpd.document_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_personnel_info AS tpi ON tpd.personnel_id=tpi.id 
and tpi.lastJoinedVsl = 4 and tpi.emp_status = 'ON-BOARD'
LEFT JOIN tbl_contracts AS tc ON tpi.id=tc.personnel_id 
and tc.personnel_status = 'ACTIVE' AND tc.vessel_id = 4
LEFT JOIN tbl_vessels AS tv ON tpi.lastJoinedVsl=tv.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT tpd.document_id
                FROM tbl_personnel_documents AS tpd
                WHERE td.id = tpd.document_id
                )
```

**Please notice**

You were using `Where` condition for the tables you used for `LEFT JOIN` which is wrong, they should be used in `JOIN` condition which i used.

Comment: If it helps you sort out your issue, don't forget to mark this answer as useful(upvote) and accept the answer [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You get null for the name using this query.

Comment: Isn't it logical? How it could have value for name?

Comment: The OP has the name in their query so the question may be what documents does kevin (or any other person that fits the conditions) not have, no doubt OP will come back with clarification.

Comment: I don't think that is logical. Kevin does not have that document means he has no relation with it, so the name can't be shown for all names. If he wants only for Kevin, then it is possible! Anyway if you have any idea, please go to the fiddle link and do it and let me know.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I think it is lacking a result, I also need to get the name which is Kevin Like P.Salmon said. Isn't that possible to get the two result? What I want is to display the name of a personnel  and display his missing document.

Comment: As i said already, this is not possible for all personnel in your current DB design and requirements. But if you only want it for 'Kevin', then you can use [THIS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46790e/112)